# JavaFX WebEngine timeout handling

Tags: webview, javafx, timeout

I'm wondering if anyone has figured out a way to properly handle timeouts in the JavaFX 8 (jdk 1.8.0_31) `WebView`. The problem is the following:

> Consider you have an instance of `WebView` and you tell it to `load` a specific URL. Furthermore, you want to process the document once it's loaded, so you attach a listener to the `stateProperty` of the `LoadWorker` of the `WebEngine` powering the web view. However, a certain website times out during loading, which causes the stateProperty to transition into `Worker.State.RUNNING` and remain stuck there.

The web engine is then completely stuck. I want to implement a system that detects a timeout and cancels the load. To that end, I was thinking of adding a listener to the `progressProperty` and using some form of `Timer`. The idea is the following:

> We start a load request on the web view. A timeout timer starts running immediately. On every progress update, the timer is reset. If the progress reaches 100%, the timer is invalidated and stopped. However, if the timer finishes (because there are no progress updates in a certain time frame we assume a time out), the load request is cancelled and an error is thrown.

Does anyone know the best way to implement this?

Kind regards

**UPDATE**

I've produced a code snippet with behavior described in the question. The only thing still troubling me is that I can't cancel the `LoadWorker`: calling `LoadWorker#cancel` hangs (the function never returns).

```
public class TimeOutWebEngine implements Runnable{

    private final WebEngine engine = new WebEngine();
    private ScheduledExecutorService exec;
    private ScheduledFuture<?> future;
    private long timeOutPeriod;
    private TimeUnit timeOutTimeUnit;

    public TimeOutWebEngine() {
        engine.getLoadWorker().progressProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
            if (future != null) future.cancel(false);
            if (newValue.doubleValue() < 1.0) scheduleTimer();
            else cleanUp();
        });
    }

    public void load(String s, long timeOutPeriod, TimeUnit timeOutTimeUnit){
        this.timeOutPeriod = timeOutPeriod;
        this.timeOutTimeUnit = timeOutTimeUnit;
        exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        engine.load(s);
    }

    private void scheduleTimer(){
        future = exec.schedule(TimeOutWebEngine.this, timeOutPeriod, timeOutTimeUnit);
    }

    private void cleanUp(){
        future = null;
        exec.shutdownNow();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
       System.err.println("TIMED OUT");
//     This function call stalls...
//     engine.getLoadWorker().cancel();
       cleanUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide example of site which cause your problem?

Comment: This is of course a volatile nature, but as of right now, this url is loading extremely slowly: http://www.northsearegion.eu/ivb/projects/details/&tid=122&back=yes , or at least for me... Note that it does *eventually* load, but in the past I've ran into actual time outs that caused my process to "deadlock".

Comment: http://www.northsearegion.eu/ivb/projects/details/&tid=76&back=yes is also extremely slow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can handle timeouts properly now. Looks at this [method](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u40/rt/file/64d2b6d3a2a3/modules/web/src/main/java/com/sun/webkit/network/URLLoader.java#l272). As you can see it has hardcoded value for `setReadTimeout` method. Is it mean that SocketTimeoutException exception will be raised after one hour of loading site. And state will be changed to FAILED only after that event.

So, you have only one way now: try to hack this problem use Timers as you described above.

P.S.
  Try to create issue in [JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa). May be anyone fixed it after 5 years...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and used a simple PauseTransition. Same behavior, not so complicated. =)